# Combine Flask-Marshmallow with marshmallow-jsonapi

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

## Overview

I am using Flask-SqlAlchemy and now I am looking into marshmallow to help me serialize and deserialize request data.

I was able to successfully:

1. Create my models using **Flask-SqlAlchemy**
2. Use **Flask-Marshmallow** to serialize database objects using the same model, by using the [Optional Flask-SqlAlchemy Integration](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#optional-flask-sqlalchemy-integration)
3. Use **marshmallow-jsonapi** to quickly generate Json API compliant responses. This required me to [declare new Schemas](https://marshmallow-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#declaring-schemas) to specify which attributes  I want to include (this is duplicate from Flask-SqlAlchemy Models)

## Code Samples

#### Flask-SqlAlchemy Declarative Model

```
class Space(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'spaces'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sql.Column(sql.String)
    version = sql.Column(sql.String)
    active = sql.Column(sql.Boolean)
```

#### flask_marshmallow Schema Declaration (Inherits from SqlAlchemy Model)

```
ma = flask_marshmallow.Marshmallow(app)

class SpaceSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Space

# API Response
space = Space.query.first()
return SpaceSchema().dump(space).data

# Returns:
{
'id': 123,
'version': '0.1.0',
'name': 'SpaceName',
'active': True
}
```

#### marshmallow_json api - requires new Schema Declaration, must include each attribute and type manually

```
class SpaceJsonSchema(marshmallow_json.Schema):
    id = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()
    version = fields.Str()
    active = fields.Bool()

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'spaces'
        self_url = '/spaces/{id}'
        self_url_kwargs = {'id': '<id>'}
        self_url_many = '/spaces/'
        strict = True

# Returns Json API Compliant
{
    'data': {
        'id': '1',
        'type': 'spaces',
        'attributes': {
            'name': 'Phonebooth',
            'active': True,
            'version': '0.1.0'
         },
        'links': {'self': '/spaces/1'}
    },
    'links': {'self': '/spaces/1'}
}
```

## Issue

As shown in the code, **marshmallow-jsonapi** allows me to create json api compliant responses, but I end up having to maintain a Declarative Model + Schema Response model.

**flask-marshmallow** allows me to create Schema responses from the SqlAlchemy models, so I don't have to maintain a separate set of properties for each model.

---

### Question

Is it at all possible to use **flask-marshmallow** and **marshmallow-jsonapi** together so 1. Create Marshmallow Schema from a SqlAlchemy model, **AND** automatically generate json api responses?

I tried creating  Schema declaration that inherited from `ma.ModelSchema` and `marshmallow_json.Schema`, in both orders, but it does not work (raises exception for missing methods and properties)

---

#### [marshmallow-jsonapi](https://marshmallow-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

> marshmallow-jsonapi provides a simple way to produce JSON
>   API-compliant data in any Python web framework.

#### [flask-marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> Flask-Marshmallow includes useful extras for integrating with
>   Flask-SQLAlchemy and marshmallow-sqlalchemy.

Comment: looks like you can do some multiple inheritence in python i.e. `class MyClass(Schema, SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes

i'm trying to get this to work now too

Comment: looks like someone else already did... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035144

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to this exact problem but I ran into similar issues when implementing this library : https://github.com/thomaxxl/safrs (sqlalchemy + flask-restful + jsonapi compliant spec). 
I don't remember exactly how I got around it, but if you try it and serialization doesn't work I can help you resolve it if you open an issue in github

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion. I ended up just building schemas with marshmallow_jsonapi for now. Turned out a lot of them required some tweaks to play nice with serializer/deserializer, so I am not sure an out of the box solution would have resolved it.